# Trying to add listen events in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, https

I am trying to add listener events to my httpsServer but I am having troubles passing the right parameters/types

```js
this.httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
this.httpsServer.on("error", onError);
this.httpsServer.on("listening", onListening(this.httpsServer));

export const onListening = (httpsServer: https.Server) => {
    const addrress = httpsServer.address();
    const bind = typeof addrress === "string"
        ? "pipe " + addrress
        : "port " + addrress.port;
    debug.info(`Listening on ${bind}`);
};
```

The error event does work but for the listening event I get: `// Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
this.httpsServer.on("listening", onListening(this.httpsServer));
```

You're passing the result of `onListening(this.httpsServer)` as the second argument to `on`, but `onListening` returns `void`.

I think what you meant to do is this:

```
this.httpsServer.on("listening", () => onListening(this.httpsServer));
```

This passes a function to `on` that calls `onListening` whenever the `"listening"` event is received.

You can also return a function from your current `onListening` function:

```
export const onListening = (httpsServer: https.Server) => () => {
  const addrress = httpsServer.address();
  const bind = typeof addrress === "string"
      ? "pipe " + addrress
      : "port " + addrress.port;
  debug.info(`Listening on ${bind}`);
}
```